# Array outputs 0000 when i input only numbers

Tags: java, arrays

The program is suppose to take a line of input from a text file.

The program will get the width of a 2d array from command line, then find the appropriate height, input the characters row by row, and encipher them by outputting column by column.

```
static void loadUnloadGrid(String line, int width, int height) {
   char grid[][] = new char[height][width];

   // Determine number long columns
   int longColumn = line.length() % width;
   if (longColumn == 0)
      longColumn = width;


   int charCount = 0;
   //
   System.out.println(width);
   height = height;
   System.out.println(height);


   //
   for (int c = 0; c < height; c++) {
      for (int r = 0; r < width; r++) {
         if (c < height - 1 || c < longColumn) {
            grid[c][r] = line.charAt(charCount);
            charCount += 1;
         }
      }
   }

   // Output data from the grid by rows
   System.out.printf("Grid width %d: \"", width);
   for (int r = 0; r < width - 1; r++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < height; c++) {
         System.out.print(grid[c][r]);
      }
   }
   // Special handling for last row
   for (int c = 0; c < longColumn; c++) {
      System.out.print(grid[height - 1][c]);
   }

}
```

### Input:

> FRIENDSROMANSCOUNTRYMENLENDMEYOUREARSICOMETOBURYCAESARNOTTOPRAISEHIM

### Expected output:

> FNOSNMEERSMBCATRERDMCTENYEIEUARTAHISAORNDOACTRENOIIERNUYLMUROOYSOPSM

### Actual output:

> FSSREOSTCNR 0000 RRCYNUIOAOA 0000 IOOMDRCBETI 0000 EMUEMEOUSTS 0000 NANNEAMRAOE 0000 0000 0000

My output does not print out a full encipher; There are 68 original characters and it outputs 55 scrambled ones and a bunch of 0's mixed in. I'm new to java, this is for a class at school, and I have some programming experience with other language.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. What is your actual question?

Comment: You should post an example of input, expected output and *real* output, that would make your question clearer.

Comment: ok ill change that now

Comment: What is `height = height;` supposed to do?

Comment: @user3267256 wht width and height u give ?

Comment: From your excepted output , the algorithm required to pick the nth char (n is width in your example it is 3) and form new string . do like this until the complete char visited.. is that the one you want ?  then why height has to be passed as argument ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this and got a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. I am actually not sure what the zeros are an indication of. It could be something weird your IDE is doing (if you're using one). You should just get the exception.

The exception happens here:

```
grid[c][r] = line.charAt(charCount);
```

You have a check that seems to be an attempt at a guard against this but it doesn't work:

```
if (c < height - 1 || c < longColumn) {
```

It should, I think, be `r < longColumn` but that won't fix it completely since any number of columns can be an argument. The short row is not necessarily at `height - 1`.

Changing the check to the following fixes the exception:

```
if (charCount < line.length()) {
```

There also seems to be a problem with your output algorithm. Basically I gather the "cipher" is just a kind of loop inversion. So outputting the last row separately won't work because it won't be interleaved.

The following seems to be correct:

```
System.out.printf("Grid width %d: \"", width);
for (int r = 0; r < width; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < height; c++) {
        System.out.print(grid[c][r]);
    }
}

System.out.println("\"");
```

You can just print the whole grid because the rows are all the same length at this point. The empty indexes will just have null characters (UTF code 0) which won't be visible.

Called like this:

```
loadUnloadGrid("FRIENDSROMANSCOUNTRYMENLENDMEYOUREARSICOMETOBURYCAESARNOTTOPRAISEHIM", 4, 17);
```

The output is:

```
Grid width 4: "FNOSNMEERSMBCATRERDMCTENYEIEUARTAHISAORNDOACTRENOIIERNUYLMUROOYSOPSM"
```

Which is the same as your expected.